# ListBox.SelectedItem is null notification

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selecteditem

I need to track current selected item in ListBox to turn off some other controls on the form when selected item become null. I try to use SelectedIndexChanged event, but it not raise when selected item is null.

Can you please advise something?

UPDATE: Selected item becomes null because i set new DataSource value with empty collection. May be it's a reason of my problem?

I need to explain. ListBox represent collection of items from database. When user add/edit/delete some item, I refresh listbox by calling this method:

```
private void RefreshList()
{
     lbParts.DataSource = this.database.Fetch<part>(string.Empty);
}
```

It fetched all items from database, convert it to `List<part>` collection and set as ListBox DataSource.

Comment: When does it become null? Do you reload the listbox or something. The answer depends on your events...

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is incorrect.  SelectedIndexChanged is raised when SelectedItem becomes null.  In this case, SelectedIndex will be -1.

EDIT: you are indeed correct that when you change DataSource, you don't get SelectedIndexChanged.  I would recommend explicitly setting SelectedIndex=-1 immediately *before* anytime you change DataSource

Comment: something else is wrong in your code then.  how are you clearing selection?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps handle the DataSourceChanged event as well? If the choices available in the listbox change, then I assume this is reason to perform a refresh on the forms avialable controls?